# Rewrite trigonometric expression to be be numerically "stable"

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to write the following function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{x-\sin x}{1- \cos x}& x\neq 0\\
  0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
as a composition of elementary functions (including $\mathrm{sinc} (x) = (\sin x) / x)$ so that I get not large numerical errors for $x$ close to zero?

This is the complete list of functions I can use: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html

This formula is used to compute the area of a circular segment with fixed chord length and given angle.

**addendum**

I found I can write:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\frac{x}{\sin x} - 1}{x} \frac{x}{\sin x}.
$$
But this is not resolutive. Seems to me that the derivative of the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function cannot be explicitly written in terms of the extended elementary function listed in the link above.

Comment: The problem is known as [Loss of significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) which happens when you substract two floating point values that are very close to each other. You do this both in the numerator as well as in the denominator. But I was not able to find a solutions of far.

Comment: Perhpas you can use the taylor series when you are near zero, few terms should already leat to a accurate result: [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+%28x-sin%28x%29%29%2F%281-cos%28x%29%29)

Comment: Some ideas: 1) Use a Taylor expansion, 2) Use variable precision arithmetic. For example, in Matlab you can use `syms x; vpa(subs((x-sin(x))/(1-cos(x)),x,0.1))`

Comment: Yes, I could use Taylor series, but I should distinguish the case when x is not small... that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the first two members of the Taylor series of the numerator and the denominator then you get

$$\frac{x-\sin x}{1- \cos x}\approx \frac{x}{3}.$$

The error of this approximation is less than $10^{-8}$ over the interval $(-0.01,0.01).$

Comment: The next approximation is $x\frac{20-x^2}{60-5x^2}$ (by Taylor).

Comment: Yes, this is nice! However I need to apply this formula also for "non small" values of $x$. I think I could use $x/3$ when $|x| < 0.01$ and the exact formula elsewhere...

Comment: Yes, or you could use @YvesDaoust's even more precise approx around zero. I just wanted to give a very simple version that does not require division of small numbers. But not exactly elsewhere...

Comment: I thought you'd like to avoid distinguishing cases?

Comment: As far as I can tell: No, you cannot. But I am not a numerical analyst.

Comment: Sorry, my question was directed at @EmanuelePaolini because before you answered he said he does not want to distinguish cases when we suggested using taylor series for small x.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer a formula which is exact and which is defined at x=0. But maybe such a formula does not exist...

Comment: @ Emanuele Paolini. I can build for you higher order Pade approximants you could use between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ and never use any tirgonometric function and keep high accuracy. Just post if you want them (but tell me how large you accepr error).

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as  Yves Daoust, for more accuracy than using Taylor series, you could use Pade approximants. The simplest one would be $$\frac{x-\sin x}{1- \cos x}\approx \frac{x \left(420-x^2\right)}{45 \left(28-x^2\right)}$$ The error is extremely small : $\approx 10^{-15}$ over the interval $(-0.01,0.01)$.

Another  could be $$\frac{x-\sin x}{1- \cos x}\approx \frac{x \left(x^4+12600\right)}{1260 \left(30-x^2\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$$\frac{x}{\sin ^2x}+\frac{x}{\tan \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{\sin \left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{\tan \left(x\right)}$$
which is equal to the original function, though it is still undefined at 0. It is also equal to
$$\frac{x+x\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(x\right)}{\sin ^2\left(x\right)}$$

Comment: Can you explain why this should behave any better than the original function? In my opinion this behaves even worse.

Comment: It does the exact same thing, but OP wants a function with only the elementary functions such as sin, cos, etc. (that's how I understand it anyway) If that's not what OP wants then this function isn't any better.

Comment: No, as far as I understand OP wants to reduce numerical errors near 0.